# How i style when same elements in one place?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I have a trouble with styling my components. When i built my structure like this:

```
<dom-module id="content-area">
   <template>
      <my-button class='red'>Hello</my-button>
      <my-button class='green'>Hello</my-button>
   </template>
</dom-module>
```

And how i style it with external html file `custom-style.html`

```
<custom-style>
   <style is="custom-style">
       :host(.red) {
          color: red;
       }
       :host(.green) {
          color: green;
       }
   </style>
</custom-style>
```

What did i do wrong ? Any advice ?

Comment: The answers you already have cover what you asked, I just wanted to add, as a note, that for things like this you can also use another approach. Say you want to use more "semantic" names, so you won't lock into using "red" and "green" even if you decide to update the colors. Your elements could have something like theme/type that would be, for example, "error" or "success", and to define the actual color codes you would use some custom CSS properties like `--my-error-color` and `--my-success-color`, as described here: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/custom-css-properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to use a custom-style, which you may share with your all components: 
As @Alberto Marin explained, include the style file

```
<link rel="import" href="custom-style.html">
<dom-module id="content-area">
  <template>
    <style include="custom-stle">
    </style>
     <my-button class='red'>Hello</my-button>
     <my-button class='green'>Hello</my-button>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

And at custom-style.html wrap your style block in  and  elements, like this:

```
<dom-module id="custom-style">
  <template>
    <style>
      <!-- Your shared styles -->
    </style>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to style your component with an external file you have to do it as the Polymer documentation says : https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/style-shadow-dom

In your case, where you have the component:

```
<link rel="import" href="custom-style.html">
```

on `custom-style.html`

```
<style>
:host(.red) {
          color: red;
       }
       :host(.green) {
          color: green;
       }
</style>
```